# PHP print stdClass objects

Tags: php

I have the following stdClass, how can I print the objects data inside?

```
Array
(
    [USD] => stdClass Object
        (
            [15m] => 94.60177
            [last] => 94.60177
            [buy] => 94.61019
            [sell] => 94.66024
            [24h] => 94.51
            [symbol] => $
        )

    [CNY] => stdClass Object
        (
            [15m] => 580.38036
            [last] => 580.38036
            [buy] => 569.24441
            [sell] => 593.90802
            [24h] => 577.26
            [symbol] => Â¥
        )
)
```

I need to access for example USD->15m
Tried with something like `$blockchain_array->USD->15m` with no luck.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go.

```
echo $blockchain_array['USD']->{'15m'};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$blockchain_array['USD']->{'15m'}
```

Comment: You are forgetting the quotes in {15m}

Comment: for all objects work but not for `15m` and `24h` that I get syntax error: `syntax error, unexpected 'm' (T_STRING)`